# Laravel count most repeated items

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to know which are the most repeated instances of a column in a model.

I have `User` model and I'll like to know which were the type of payments most used by them

I have a foreign key to the table payments where I save the `payments_id`.

```
$users_payments = scm\User::lists('payment_id');
```

With this I get `["16","0","15","14","14","0","15","14"]`, where those numbers are the `id` of each type of payment, I would like to get the three most repeated.

Comment: Can you show your user and payments table structure ?

Comment: When you have query to make and don't know where to go, write it first in SQL, so in your case you would use a GROUP BY payment_id, a COUNT and a SORT BY, then try to translate it to Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do not want to do with an Eloquent query, you could process the array later with standard php array functions:

```
$users_payment = scm\User::lists('payment_id');
```

[array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) counts the occurrences of an item

```
$occurrences = array_count_values($user_payment);
```

Now sort it high to low with [arsort()](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
arsort($occurrences);
```

And take the first 3 with [array_slice():](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$items = array_slice($occurrences, 0, 3);
```

Comment: I already tryed that the problem is that array_count_values function only works with int and string, i thought it should get this, but it shows me that error